# share intent view in my xml

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-sharing

I want to share a simple text using intent here is a simple code :

```
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_with)));
```

I just want to show this in my XML layout not another view like pop up or dialog.
how can I achieve that?do we have an XML tag that I put in my XML file?

Comment: what you have did so for

Comment: I can get intent contents and show in a recycle view but i want to know that do we have another way to open share intent in my XML view. @Anil

Comment: So you want to create your own custom share intent and also want to handle in your own app rather than sharing it through some external apps?

Comment: What is your xml view?